# git post_deploy hook list of changed files (openshift)

Tags: git, openshift

I'm running a python app in openshift. I have a post_deploy hook that imports a mysql database from a dump file.

I'd like to only load the dump if it was actually included in this push. Is there a way for my hook to get information about what files where included in the push?

Locally I can run the following command:

```
git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD
```

But when my post_deploy hook runs it is on the openshift side and the git commands don't work.

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try running that command in your app-root/git directory, that is an actual git repo and may give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: There is no git directory in app-root. There is a git directory at the very top level, but any git command I run in there gives: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).